# How to print Multiple datasets in one proc print statement?

Tags: sas

I have an sas query that if I have created 3 datasets, lets say named as `ds1, ds2, ds3`. Now, I want to print all of them under one proc print statement, then how can we do that? Like, i want something like: `proc print data = work.ds1 work.ds2 work.ds3; run;`

Is there some way to do this? Please make sure that I want these to be printed in ONE OR SINGLE PROC PRINT statement.

Comment: It's certainly not possible to do that. But if you explain why you'd want that (what's wrong with doing 3 proc prints for instance), maybe we can offer some advice. Also, do your datasets all have the same structure?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot print multiple datasets from one `proc print` statement.  You could concatenate the datasets into one, but they wouldn't be separate datasets at that point.

If your concern is getting them into a particular output, provide more information as to your desired results.  Thanks to some ODS features, you may be able to get something similar to your desired results.