# Sorting multiple tables in one PROC SORT

Tags: sas

For a SAS program I am writing, I am needing to do the equivalent of full outer joining 4 different work tables into a single table. I was initially just going to do it in a `PROC SQL` but that quickly got out of hand, so I instead decided to set it up with a `MERGE` in a data step.

As an example:

```
proc sort data = TABLE_1; by COL1 COL2 COL3;
proc sort data = TABLE_2; by COL1 COL2 COL3;
proc sort data = TABLE_3; by COL1 COL2 COL3;
proc sort data = TABLE_4; by COL1 COL2 COL3;

data NEW_TABLE;
    merge TABLE_1 TABLE_2 TABLE_3 TABLE_4;
    by COL1 COL2 COL3;
```

It seems kind of cumbersome to need to sort each table individually by the same exact field set. I've set up a macro variable to be equivalent to the list of column names, but I still have to have one line for each table.

Is there a way to write something to execute a `PROC SORT` on multiple tables at once, if they all have the same columns? From what I know of SAS, I would expect something like this to work:

```
proc sort data = (TABLE_1 TABLE_2 TABLE_3 TABLE_4); by COL1 COL2 COL3;
```

Or even something like this, if the tables were numbered like in this example:

```
proc sort data = (TABLE_1-TABLE_4); by COL1 COL2 COL3;
```

But I've not been able to get either to work. Admittedly I haven't tried setting it up through an array, but mostly because that seems like overkill for such a short list of tables (and a longer list of tables would probably warrant a different merging solution altogether).

Judging from the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36409912/4927169), I'm not optimistic about performing PROCs on multiple tables at once in general, though perhaps sorting works differently.

Comment: Remember that MERGE and FULL JOIN handle many to many matches differently.

Comment: `proc sql` can join multiple tables at once, without sorting first, but it may not be very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have 1 `PROC SORT` and have it sort multiple tables.  You can create a macro to write the cumbersome code for you.  Like this

```
%macro sortem(tables,byvar);
%local i n table;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&tables));
%do i=1 %to &n;
   %let table=%scan(&tables,&i);
   proc sort data=&table;
   by &byvar;
   run;
%end;
%mend;
```

Then call

```
%sortem(table_1 table_2 table_3 table_4, COL1 COL2 COL3);
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. I didn't have much hope for there being a "yes" to my question, but I honestly couldn't find anything one way or another when I searched around. Though this would seem like overkill for my small number of tables, looping the PROC seems like the best solution overall.

Comment: The good thing about this macro is that it works for 1 table as well as 1000 tables.  Write the macro once, include it in all your code, and use it instead of PROC SORT when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth a second answer.  If you have a recent version of SAS, you can use `PROC DS2` to do your merge.  DS2 does not require you to have presorted the tables.  See the example below:

```
data table1;
do x=1 to 100;
    a = rannor(1);
    output;
end;
run;

data table2; /*Reverse order*/
do x=100 to 1 by -1;
    b = rannor(2);
    output;
end;
run;

data table3;
do x=1 to 100;
    c = rannor(3);
    output;
end;
run;

proc sort data=table3; /*Make Table3 out of order*/
by c;
run;

proc ds2 ;
data work.comb /overwrite=yes;
  method run();
    merge table1 table2 table3;
    by x;
  end;
enddata;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Interesting, though it doesn't look like my version of SAS has it (I'm on 9.3, and `PROC DS2` appears in 9.4 from what I can tell). Nice to know that my question can just be side-stepped in more advanced versions.